# Vuetify v-file-input "onchange" working but not getting the event

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Please take a look at my code below. My `input` works well, but not the `v-file-input`:

```
<v-file-input
  accept=".json"
  ref="loadedFile"
  label="Upload file"
  @change="checkJSON"
  ></v-file-input>

<input
    type="file"
    accept=".json"
    @change="checkJSON"
    >



methods: {
  checkJSON: function(e) {
    console.log("JSON checking")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    console.log(e.target.files)
    return
  }
}
```

The console shows the file for the `input`, but here is the message I get for the `v-file-input`:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: e.target is undefined"
```

Is that normal? I'd like to use the vuetify component, it's prettier.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Acording to [Vuetify doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/) to `v-file-input`, `@change` event has 1 param which is an array of Files.

```
checkJSON: function(files) {
    console.log(files)
}
```

This event is diferent to `@change` from your input.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand what they meant by "File[]".